# slurm trouble from emacs

Tags: emacs, slurm

After a recent `slurm` update `slurm` scripts are not working when I'm trying to run them (as I did before) via a remote shell from emacs. I get the following error messages:

```
fabig@login-0:~$ sbatch --wrap "ls"
sbatch: error: slurm_receive_msg: Zero Bytes were transmitted or received
sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Zero Bytes were transmitted or
        received
```

The strange thing is that the same command works perfectly fine when I'm running it from the (OSX) terminal (after `ssh` into the remote).

So if anyone has an idea how to solve this, I would be very grateful!

Comment: Is any of the other slurm commands working? Are the slurm commands only failing on login-0? If slurm has been upgraded maybe the munge daemon is not running or the slurm version in login-0 is incompatible with the version running the controller

Comment: Hi Carles thanks for the feedback! It does look indeed like version trouble. For some mysterious reason the wrong `slurm` version is loaded when using `emacs-tramp`.

Comment: in `emacs` slurm 2.6.4 is loaded, while when logging in by terminal slurm 16.05.0pre is loaded. Mysterious but, I think this I can fix ...